# 1 USB device, 1 USB host, ability to copy/paste text

Tags: usb, keyboards

I'm working on a proof-of-concept for a project and I need a device to sit between a keyboard and a laptop/desktop. The device will have two modes: "regular mode" where it passes along all input it receives from the keyboard as keystrokes, and "secure mode" where it loads all input from the keyboard into the clipboard, pastes it on a button press, and immediately clears the clipboard.  I'd like to use USB for ease of use.  Since it's a proof of concept, I don't need perfectly suited hardware for now (i.e., if a Raspberry Pi or Arduino can this, that works). It should ideally be powered by the computer, but that's not a requirement at this point.

Comment: I think I see what you are after with the "Secure Mode", but I don't think it is going to work the way you want. The clipboard is an OS feature, meaning that in order for the device to work they way you describe, it would have to send all data to the computer which will store it in the clipboard instead of directly writing it out. Since it passes through the OS, it is not as secure as you want it. If the device had a buffer, it would still have to send the data as keystrokes. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: So there is no way to transfer any data directly into RAM?  I got the idea from the `cudaMemcpy` function in the CUDA library.  Is there an equivalent in C/C++?

Comment: @silvertiger You can definitely write a C/C++ driver that will do this! But, that driver will be running on top of the OS. The middleman device you're making will have to interface with the hardware, which is controlled by the OS. The OS will pick up all input and pass it along to your driver, but it _will_ see it all.

Perhaps a better "secure" mode would be to have all your input encrypted, in such a way that only your driver can decrypt it. Aside from that, Linux is open-source; you could write your own OS.

Comment: What is the gist? To prevent [keyloggers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging) from seeing what is going on?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yep, that was the idea. Immediately clearing the clipboard was also supposed to foil anything that was grabbing the contents of the clipboard, but modern OSes keep a history of their clipboards now.